# Container overlapping header image

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, containers, css-position

I build websites from scratch using bootstrap and have a question regarding containers/positioning.

I am going to be building a section where a container overlaps the header image (screenshot example attached). I was wondering if anyone has examples of this being used or knows what the technique is called so I can have a look into other examples?

The way to do it will be using absolute positioning but I'd just like to see some other examples of peoples attempts before I do my own!

Thanks for all your help.

[image: Container Overlapping Header Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we need to see the structure of your html to know how it's formed and apply the css rules accordingly.
But in case you don't have it, here is an example using negative margin:

```css
.first {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.second {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 60%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -80px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Adriana. Of course, I wouldn't expect a perfectly working example without seeing my HTML. In your opinion is a negative margin better than absolute positioning?

Comment: @NathanClancy Yes, in my opinion I always try to avoid absolute positioning, because if you are not very careful, the element can go out of place in different device resolutions. It has happened to me many times in the past

Comment: @NathanClancy I mean you can use position absolute if you want, there is no problem with it as it is fully supported, it is only my opinion. What I'm saying is that "position: absolute" may have side-effect if you are not aware of the details or not sure how to use it ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your advice!  I have just tested using negative margin and you are right, its much easier to control than absolute positioning. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

i have tried doing this before, and i used `z-index: -1` for the image.